# jQuery: Sliding up an element and replacing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm trying to use jQuery to make it so that when I click on an element, it slides up, and a new element is created which slides down into its place.

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/V4SVt/474/

```
$('.grab_button').click(function () {
    $(this).slideUp(function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span class=" grabbed">grabbed</span>').hide());
        $(this).parent().children('.grabbed').slideDown();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

When I click on the element, it slides out perfectly, and the new element is created, however it does not slide down. It just appears. If I then hide the element and then slide it down via the WebKit console, it animates correctly. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are issues with sliding inline elements, especially if they are inserted dynamically and have no position, size or anything else.

Try this:

```
$('.grab_button').click(function () {
    var assGrab = $('<span />', {'class':'grabbed', text:'grabbed', style:'display:inline-block;'});
    $(this).slideUp(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith(assGrab.hide());
        assGrab.slideDown()
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4SVt/475/)

Comment: Is there anything particularly wrong with the code I wrote (ie. it shouldn't work, even in theory)?

Comment: @jdp407 - not really, if you used a div instead of a span your code would probably work as well.